# LC-3 program with 3 bugs (2 syntax and 1 logic)

Tags: assembly, lc3

I have the following LC-3 program with 3 bugs (2 syntax and 1 logic):

```
        .ORIG       x3000
        LD          R1, N
        AND         R2, R2, #0
LOOP    BRz         DONE
        ADD         R2, R2, R1
        ADD         R1, R1, #-1
        BRnzp       LOOP
DONE    ST          TOTAL
N       .FILL       x000B
TOTAL   .BLKW       #1
        .STOP
```

I thought there were no bugs but showed my professor and he said there were 3 (2 syntax and 1 logic). I need to figure out what the bugs are in my program but I am stumped. Does anybody have any input on this? Any resources that can help me understand LC-3 programs better?

Comment: Have you tried *actually running the program*?  That would immediately locate any syntax errors.  (Finding a logic error would require that the finder have some idea of what the program is supposed to do.)

Comment: Yes when I run it I get a compilation error in line 4: "invalid operand 'RZ DONE'. You may have supplied an undeclared label" I can't seem to figure out if it is because of incorrect branch NZP bits or invalid operation.

Comment: "*invalid operand 'RZ DONE*" — strange, this code doesn't give this error on my LC-3 setup, so not sure how to help with that.  Try using a comma character after your labels, maybe that will help with your tooling, so like "`LOOP, BRz ...`".  Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: There are indeed 2 syntax errors, which are otherwise easy to find by running the code through an assembler such as http://wchargin.com/lc3web/.

Comment: Further, there is also one logic error, which comes from improper loop construction. Can you write the equivalent loop in C or other? If so, maybe that will help you see the issue.  Alternatively, fix the syntax errors and run it in the simulator, and you'll see that it doesn't work because of loop control issues.

Comment: Interesting, when I put it into https://spacetech.github.io/LC3Simulator/ it gives me an error on line 4 but in wchargin.com/lc3web it doesn't. I did realize that the .STOP line should be .END and the ST instruction has the wrong number of operands. Still looking for a third error because when I make those corrections it assembles just fine in the simulator.

Comment: Ok, so have you tried running it then?  You'll find it doesn't work and that's the logic error that needs fixing.  I think it is supposed to sum numbers to N by repetitive addition, but it doesn't.  Might be good to update the question to append your latest code (don't necessarily delete the original though b/c the comments here relate to that).

Comment: Also, your code snippet is missing a `HALT` statement, so after the ST instruction, it begins to execute the data (which is bad)